# Calling one parameter in another function?

Tags: javascript

Actually i want to take url and id from one fn to another whether this method will work.

```
function addElement(url, id) {
    alert(url);
    var main = document.getElementById('mainwidget');
    main.innerHTML = "<iframe src=" + url + " align='left' height='1060px' width='576px' scrolling='no'  frameborder='0' id='lodex'></iframe>";
    alert("google");
    addUrl(url, id);
}
function add() {
    addUrl(url, id)
    alert("id" + id);
    document.getElementById("Listsample").innerHTML = "<a href='#' onclick='addUrl(" + url + ");' id='cricket' tabindex='1' name='cricket'>" + id + "</a>";
}
```

Comment: No this will not work as you have written it.

Comment: Could you clean up this code to only contain the pieces relevant to your question? Otherwise it's hard to guess what your question is. Also, where do you call add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to share the information somehow, because *`variables`* are only available in their function's *`scope`*. The simplest way is to define global variables.

```
var url, id; // global

function addElement(_url, _id) {
    url = _url;
    id  = _id;
    alert(url);
    var main = document.getElementById('mainwidget');
    main.innerHTML = "<iframe>...</iframe>";
    alert("google");
    addUrl(url, id);
},

function add() {
    addUrl(url, id)
    alert("id" + id);
    document.getElementById("Listsample").innerHTML = "<a>...</a>";
}
```

Note that they don't need to be global. You can wrap this module into its own *`scope`*

```
(function() {

/// code goes here

})();
```

Or you can also organize the whole code into an object (*`encapsulation`*).

```
var addy = {

    url: null, 
    id: null,

    addElement: function(url, id) {
        this.url = url;
        this.id  = id;
        alert(url);
        var main = document.getElementById('mainwidget');
        main.innerHTML = "<iframe>...</iframe>";
        alert("google");
        addUrl(url, id);
    },

    add: function() {
        addUrl(this.url, this.id);
        alert("id" + this.id);
        document.getElementById("Listsample").innerHTML = "<a>...</a>";
    }
};
```

​